# Filechannel position and string length

Tags: java, string-length, filechannel

In Java chars are 2 bytes long, But when I write a string to a file using a bytebuffer the filechannel position increments by the number of chars. I read that the Filechannel.position() method returns the number of bytes from the beginning of the file to the current position so shoudnt it increment by 2*numberof chars?.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not quite. In Java, the `char` type is twice the bit width of the `byte` type, but that only means chars *can be* two bytes long. It depends on your String's character encoding, but with UTF-8 encoding (the default), chars are encoded as only one byte for chars between 0 and 127, but multiple bytes for chars over this range (when the high bit is set, it means the next byte is also part of the current char)

For Strings made of only 0-127 characters (ie "normal text"), byte length will equal char length.

If your String contains characters outside the range 0-127, byte length will be greater than the number of characters.

Comment: SO if a string that I write to a file contained both ascii and unicode chars then is the whole file treated as unicode?

Comment: @dasman the whole file treated as unicode ANYWAY, regardless of what chars you have

Comment: UTF-8 has [single-byte encoding for code points in 0-127](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description), multi-byte outside of that range. UTF-8 being the default encoding depends on your platform. The char primitive represents an UTF-16 code unit which, at the time of Java's inception, was considered sufficient to hold all declared Unicode characters (using UCS-2).

Answer (score 1):

> In Java chars are 2 bytes long

Inside the JVM. When written out they can be 1-4 bytes long depending on the character set.

> But when I write a string to a file
>   using a bytebuffer the filechannel
>   position increments by the number of
>   chars.

No, it increments by the number of bytes.

> I read that the Filechannel.position()
>   method returns the number of bytes
>   from the beginning of the file to the
>   current position so shoudnt it
>   increment by 2*numberof chars?

No. Your question is founded on two fallacies.